# react-redux-form Radio Field not updating checked prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js, react-redux-form

I've got a component that creates a field with list of Radio inputs. The created component seems to work, it is rendered correctly, dispatches the proper redux actions, and update it's state properly. However the selected radio input never gets checked in the UI.

```
import React from 'react';
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes';
import { Field } from 'react-redux-form/immutable';

const RadioField = ({ fieldId, label, model, hasError, options }) => {
  const error = hasError ? 'has-error' : '';
  return (
    <div className={`form-group ${error}`}>
      <label className="control-label" htmlFor={fieldId}>{label}</label>
      <Field model={model} id={fieldId} >
        {options.map(option => (
          <label
            key={`${fieldId}-${option.get('id')}`}
            htmlFor={`radio-${fieldId}-${option.get('value')}`}
            className="radio-inline"
          >
            <input
              id={`radio-${fieldId}-${option.get('value')}`}
              value={`${option.get('value')}`}
              type="radio"
            />
            {option.get('display')}
          </label>
        ))}
      </Field>
    </div>
  );
};

RadioField.defaultProps = {
  fieldId: 'radio-field-id',
  label: 'Radio Field:',
  model: '.radio',
  hasError: false,
  options: Immutable.List(),
};

RadioField.propTypes = {
  fieldId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  model: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  hasError: PropTypes.bool,
  options: ImmutablePropTypes.listOf(
    ImmutablePropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
      display: PropTypes.string,
      value: PropTypes.any,
    }),
  ).isRequired,
};

export default RadioField;
```

My gut tells me it has something to do with the `Field` not being able to properly locate the input that has the selected value or the redux state isn't getting passed properly to the `Field`'s children `Control` components.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the issue more and it turned out the created immutable `Control.radio` components weren't getting the modelValue from the app's redux state. Changing the component from a `Field` with inputs to multiple generic `Control` components and giving them the proper props for a radio input seemed to fix the issue.

Here's what the code looks like.

```
import React from 'react';
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes';
import { Control } from 'react-redux-form/immutable';

const RadioField = ({ fieldId, label, model, hasError, options }) => {
  const error = hasError ? 'has-error' : '';
  return (
    <div className={`form-group ${error}`}>
      <label className="control-label" htmlFor={fieldId}>{label}</label>
      <div id={fieldId}>
        {options.map(option => (
          <label key={`${fieldId}-${option.get('id')}`} htmlFor={`${fieldId}-${option.get('id')}`} className="radio-inline">
            <Control
              id={`${fieldId}-${option.get('id')}`}
              value={option.get('value')}
              model={model}
              isToggle
              type="radio"
            />
            {option.get('display')}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

RadioField.defaultProps = {
  fieldId: 'radio-field-id',
  label: 'Radio Field:',
  model: '.radio',
  hasError: false,
  options: Immutable.List(),
};

RadioField.propTypes = {
  fieldId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  model: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  hasError: PropTypes.bool,
  options: ImmutablePropTypes.listOf(
    ImmutablePropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
      display: PropTypes.string,
      value: PropTypes.any,
    }),
  ).isRequired,
};

export default RadioField;
```

I'll look into recreating the issue and submit a issue on react-redux-form's github.

Comment: I had the same/similar issue and my workaround was that `<Control.radio>` doesn't work but `<Control type="radio"`> does.